# How to parse .doc document without WINWORD?

Tags: python, go, cpu-word

Is there a way parse/replace text in .doc document without WINWORD using python, golang, c++ or other language? I checked structure .doc document and its looks like:

```
[1]CompObj
[5]DocumentSummaryInformation
[5]SummaryInformation
1Table
WordDocument
```

But it contains binary data in most place. Basically there is binary data.

Answer (score 1):

In golang, you could use [unidoc/unioffice](https://github.com/unidoc/unioffice), which is a pure go library for creating and processing Office Word (.docx), Excel (.xlsx) and Powerpoint (.pptx) documents.

Comment: It's proccesing only docx format.

Comment: `.doc` is a proprietary Microsoft binary format. That was the norm when Word was written. Also, there are different versions of it for different versions of Word. Only Word itself can handle all of that.